# wordpress search page don't give search results

Tags: wordpress, search

I made my own search form page and search page, But know when I search for something the search result gives back nothing I searched alot on the web and following some tutorials to find the issue but I can't. Her's the code:

searchform.php:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="visible-lg search-form arrow_box search-back navbar-form navbar-right" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="search" class="search-field form-control" size="49" placeholder="بگەڕێ" value="" name="s" title="بگەڕێ" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit search-button btn btn-default" value="بگەڕێ" />
</form>
```

search.php:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Search Page
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 news">
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                <?php
                global $wp_query;
                $total_results = $wp_query->found_posts;
                ?>
                <?php printf( __( 'ئەنجامەکانی گەڕان بۆ: %s', 'shape' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?>
                <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'search' ); ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'search' ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I tried many codes I finally found that I have to add the title or the content after the while loop, I don't know why but this is the solution I just changed the search.php:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Search Page
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 news">
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                <?php
                global $wp_query;
                $total_results = $wp_query->found_posts;
                ?>
                <?php printf( __( 'serch results for: %s', 'shape' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?>
                <br/><br/>
                <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <h4 class=""><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                    <div class="naskh"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <h4>Nothing found try something else.</h4>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```